# ¿Por qué mi pc no reconoce los códigos que escribo?

Tags: html, css

Siempre he tenido inconvenientes con mi pc al momento de poner estilos en un documento. Lo que pasa es que a pesar de que la sintáxis esté bien escrita, mi navegador no reconoce los estilos. Se supone que para tener mejor organizado todo hay que siempre intentar trabajar con archivos externos (en el caso de css), pero no, no es así, a mi no me funciona, siempre tengo que poner las etiquetas  en mi index para poder agregar los estilos, cosa que no me gusta porque queda todo "mal visto". También me pasa con eqtiquetas html, no sé por qué me pasa esto. Adjunto imágenes de un sencillo ejemplo para que vean que no me funciona. Si les funciona a ustedes probablemente sea mi pc.
ADJUNTO LINKS DE MIS 2 ARCHIVOS (HTML Y CSS): HTML: https://ibb.co/jqp0Cd
CSS: https://ibb.co/esKWky

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muestra como lo tienes originalmente, es decir por archivos por separado

Comment: No sé si te refieras a la carpeta y sub carpetas en donde tengo guardado todo. Tengo xampp, la carpeta se llama drag y está en htdocs, Dentro de drag tengo 2 sub carpetas, estilos e imagenes.

Comment: y porque no cambias de navegador, en mi caso uso firefox por varios motivos, pero el fundamental es que trabaja y soporta mucho la programacion en html y css..

Comment: Hola, podrias usar una ruta completa `/drag/estilos/estilo.css` pero tendrias que modificarlo al subirlo, la otra alternativa es crear un VHOST y poderlo trabajar sin tener que cambiar nada al momento de subir a producción

Comment: @Sebastian para empezar en html y css no se programa y eso no tiene nada que ver con el navegador eso no es una solución

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El computador no es responsable de que un sitio se vea bien o mal, funcione o no funcione, tampoco el navegador es responsable, hoy en día los sitios tienen que ser "Cross Browser" es decir que se deben de ver bien y comportar de igual manera en cualquier navegador en que se mire. En tu pantallazo detallo varios errores:

1. Estás cerrando dos veces las llaves `{}` del selector `body`.
2. Estas abriendo una etiqueta `<style>` dentro de otra etiqueta `<style>`.

En los comentarios te dicen que coloques la ruta completa **Eso es una pésima práctica** nunca se debe colocar la ruta completa de nada, sea una imagen, una hoja de estilos, un archivo JavaScript o lo que sea, la mejor opción es navegar entre carpetas revisando detalladamente que los archivos se encuentren en la ruta a la cual estás apuntando.

La cuestión es de revisar bien al momento de copiar el código que estés haciendo y revisar bien tu estructura de carpetas.

Comment: Lo hice como me acabas de decir, y aún así no me funciona en un archivo externo. Respecto al link que me pasaste para poder entrar al chat, no sé cómo se usa para hablar con alguien más.

Comment: @JorgeHernández tu archivo drag2.html está al lado de la carpeta 'estilos' en tu estructura? lo del chat no estoy seguro si necesitas un puntaje mínimo

Comment: Carpeta principal drag, sub carpetas imagenes y estilos. El archivo drag2.html lo tengo adentro de la carpeta drag pero por fuera de las 2 sub carpetas. Sí, me dice que para poder hablar necesito 20 puntos de reputación

Comment: @JorgeHernández siendo asi como dices la ruta debería de dar, sería bueno que mostraras entonces el archivo css que contiene, y ya tienes la reputación para hablar en el chat

Comment: No sé por dónde pasarte screens de mis 2 archivos para que veas el código. Respecto al chat, aún no puedo hablar a pesar de tener 23 puntos de reputación actuales

Comment: @JorgeHernández extraño lo del chat, y los creen adjuntalos a tu pregunta

Comment: Edité mi pregunta y adjunté 2 links de las 2 imágenes de mi código en html y css, revisa por favor. Me has ayudado todo el día, muchas gracias por la colaboración

Comment: @JorgeHernández exactamente cual es el estilo que no te da, yo veo todo bien

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, era que tenía un estilo repetido, gracias.Tengo una duda, respecto a los estilos, sé que para darlos hay que mencionar las etiquetas a las cuales se le darán. He visto que colocan body, #div o .body, ¿cómo sé cuál y cuánd poner el . o el numeral?, depende de las etiquetas?

Comment: @JorgeHernández me alegra que hayas encontrado solución, bueno, podrías leer esto para entender un poco mas sobre los selectores ya que dudo que en un comentario quepa la explicación [Selectores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Introducci%C3%B3n/Selectors)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78116/discussion-between-jorge-hernandez-and-bender).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo, he aprendido mucho hoy :)

Comment: @JorgeHernández ya puedes copiar en el chat?, de nada para eso estamos

Comment: Ahora sí ya puedo escribir en el chat. Seleccioné el primero de todos las salas que aparecen (stacko overflow en español), no sé si tú estés en esa sala

Answer (score 0):

Como escriben arriba: "el computador no es el problema".

**problemas:**

> 1. **Style** no puede estar en el `head` incluyendo el body.
> 2. Como escriben arriba, abres dos veces seguidas **style**.
> 3. **Te recomiendo crear un archivo css** e importarlo al html, como tienes puesto y  no escribir los estilos dentro del html es bastante obsoleto o para clases de introduccion.

Comment: A que te refieres con el primer punto que expones? la etiqueta style es un elemento de cabecera, por lo cual al usar estilos incrustados el lugar correcto en el que debe ir es en el head del documento.

Comment: exacto eso es lo que te estoy diciendo me he equvicado en eso ya que solo estas añadiendo estilos al body, pero no cierras la etiqueta head asique incluyes el head en todo el html.

Comment: Ademas no entiendo porque lo haces en el html si ya tienes importado una hoja de estilos.

Comment: ademas si lo estas haciendo para cambiar el estilo css solo del body o el html te recomiendo que importes hojas css dentro de  las hojas de css asi tu trabajo estará mejor definido y colocado.

Comment: Yo no soy el OP, no hice la pregunta.

Comment: Lo hago en el mismo html ya que los estilos que tenía en el otro archivo no me los reconocía, y con la etiqueta style en el head sí los reconoce o los aplica.

Comment: mirate las rutas absolutas, el archivo html tienes que estar en la carpeta antes de estilos, si no te lo reconoce eres la unica persona en el mundo que no puede hacer esto.

Comment: si eres capaz de insertar imagenes no creo que sea muy dificil lo que te digo.Puedes hacerlo directamente creando codigo en sublime y guardarlo como aarchivo.css

Comment: lo mismo te digo con el javascript, yo no se como sera tu profesor pero como vea eso te cruje.

Comment: valida primero tu html aqui https://validator.w3.org/ y veras tus errores.

Comment: y luego valida el css aqui https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: si estas en una uni o algo por el estilo cualquier profesor te dira de antes de enviarlo que lo valides en estas direcciones, por varias razones

Comment: 1etiquetas obsoletas y cosas por el estilo